# How do you drop an identity only if the identity exists and the column exists?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a script that doesn't fail if the script is run twice in a row. Lots of `IF EXISTS`. But this one is a problem:

```
ALTER TABLE alternate_id
ALTER column id
DROP IDENTITY IF EXISTS
; 

ALTER TABLE alternate_id
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS id 
;
```

Works fine the first time but after that I get `SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "id" of relation "alternate_id" does not exist`. This `id` column was added in error, it's no longer needed and should not be an identity. So I'd like to drop the identity and then drop the column but I need the script to ignore that command if the identity has already been dropped.

Comment: `ALTER COLUMN IF EXISTS` is not (yet) supported. Your script should handle the error

Comment: There's no `IF EXISTS` for `ALTER COLUMN`, even though it's available at the identity or expression level. You can instead wrap it in a procedural block and handle it in the `EXCEPTION` part or prevent it in an `IF EXISTS`. Or start the script by adding the column if it *does not* exist, regardless of whether you removed it already or it wasn't there to begin with.

Comment: ok thanks, anyone want to write up the exception block? I haven't done that in years

Comment: [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). Is there a reason why you alter before dropping instead of only dropping and prefer the procedural block over coditionally adding it in beforehand?

Comment: can you use that outside of a function or procedure? I'm just using it in a SQL script and running into cryptic errors

Comment: yeah it looks like that can only be used in functions, which is not what I'm writing https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244332/26554

Comment: @FrankHeikens how do I handle the error inside of a script (not a function)? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: @jcollum That depends mostly on your scripting language. For a language like NodeJS you can use a try/catch block

Comment: Language is SQL, as in a SQL script with no functions etc. I assumed `SQL Error` was enough of a clue there.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `alter table...alter column if exists`. You can instead: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0ykL4OI7)

1. First add the column if it *does not exist*

   ```sql
    alter table alternate_id add column if not exists id integer;     --this
    alter table alternate_id alter column id drop identity if exists;
    alter table alternate_id drop column if exists id;
   ```
2. Use an [anonymous procedural block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) to [catch and ignore the exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

   ```sql
   do $anon_proc$ begin
      alter table alternate_id alter column id drop identity if exists;
      exception when others then null; 
   end $anon_proc$;
   ```

   or prevent it

   ```sql
   do $anon_proc$ begin
        if exists (select 1 
                   from information_schema.columns 
                   where table_name='alternate_id' 
                   and column_name='id' ) then
           alter table alternate_id alter column id drop identity if exists;
        end if;
   end $anon_proc$;
   ```